# Connection strings for different users

Tags: sql, string, connection

How do I send two users coming from different company domains to different SQL databases to retrieve/store data? I use Application variables to store the connection strings and the Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") variable is an effective way to get the domain name. Is the GLOBAL.AsA file to be modified? The table names are exactly the same in both databases, so I think changing the connection strings based on the user domain should do the trick.

User A with domain ABC --> Application("ConnecttoDB") send to database A
User B with domain XYZ --> Application("ConnecttoDB") send to database B

I have roughly 900+ classic ASP pages so I would really hate to add a bunch of IF-THEN's to choose the correct database in each page. All ideas are greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: To make things simple I'm envisioning one single Application variable (i.e.: ConnecttoDB) However, wouldn't its value be constantly changing every time a different user gets access and altering page results?

Comment: I agree Global.asa is the best place to put the code.

Comment: so what is your question

Comment: How do I send two users coming from different company domains to different SQL databases to retrieve/store data?

Comment: Have we answered your question?  Please click the check mark next to the best answer to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an Application variable since that's shared across all users. This would be a race condition. Instead you'll need to use the [Session object](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp) to store the connection and then use that whenever you need to connect to the DB.

```
myDB=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
StrConn = Session("ConnecttoDB") 
myDB.Open StrConn
```

Comment: Exactly! I wasn't entirely sure about the scope of the Application variable. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

I'm guessing that your classes for your web page codebehind files inheit the `Page` class.  Create a new class file in your ASP.net project that inherits `Page`.  Call it `JorgePage`.  Then, make your codebehind file classes inherit `JorgePage`.

In `JorgePage`, write two functions:

```
private string getUsersDomain()
{
      // returns the user's domain
}

protected string getUsersConnectionString()
{
    switch (getUsersDomain().ToUpper())
    {
        case "ABC":
        return Application("ConnecttoDB_ABC");
        break;
        case "xYZ":
        return Application("ConnecttoDB_XYZ");
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, the function getUsersConnectionString() is available in the context of all your pages and returns the correct connection string.  Furthermore, you have the code in only one place, so if you need to change the logic later, you can do so easily.

Comment: I shoud have mentioned that I'm using classic ASP. Is there a way to stick to only one Application variable? The code I normally use goes like this:

sql="{some sql syntax}"
set myDB=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
StrConn = Application("ConnecttoDB")
myDB.Open StrConn

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using classic ASP, you can define a function to return the appropriate connection string in another .asp file and use the `#include` directive to add it to all your pages.